# Handle active/inactive tabs, better way other than this?

Tags: jquery, html

I have two tabs, below is the HTML code for both:

```
<input type="button" value="Activos" id="tab-active" class="active">
<input type="button" value="Inactivos" id="tab-inactive">
```

And I create this code to change between tabs:

```
$("#tab-inactive").click(function() {
    var current = $(this);

    $("#tab-active").removeClass("active");
    current.addClass("active");

    $("#layout-center").load(Routing.generate('inactive_product'));
});

$("#tab-active").click(function() {
    var current = $(this);

    $("#tab-inactive").removeClass("active");
    current.addClass("active");

    $("#layout-center").load(Routing.generate('product_list'));
});
```

The code works but I'll like to know if exists a better way/path to do this, any improvements or something around this in order to optimize and minimize the  code

Comment: You should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly changing the code above.

HTML

```
<button type="button" value="inactive_product" class="tab active">Activos</button>
<button type="button" value="product_list" class="tab">Inactivos</button>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.tab').click(function() 
{
    var $this         = $(this);
    var $tabs         = $('.tab');
    var route         = $this.val();
    var $layoutCenter = $("#layout-center");        

    $tabs.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    $layoutCenter.load(Routing.generate(route));  
});
```

Comment: Since I can't use `value` I use data-route and get that attribute your code did the job, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<input type="button" data-route="route1" value="Activos" class="tab active">
<input type="button" data-route="route2" value="Inactivos" class="tab">

$( ".tab" ).click(function() {
    var this$ = $( this );
    if ( !this$.hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
        $( '.tab.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        this$.addClass( 'active' );
        $( "#layout-center" ).load( Routing.generate( this$.data( 'route' ) ) );
    }
 } );
```

In case of **2 tabs only** even `toggleClass( 'active' )` can be used.

Comment: What about the `load()` method? Notice it changes on one or other tab, how to handle this part using your code suggestion

Comment: `load()`? What for you use it?

Comment: Well I call two different routes handled by PHP in server side

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. You can store them as tab attribute.

Comment: And then how I access them? Suppose I call those attributes `data-url` and pass `inactive_product` or `product_list` as values